# Is there a way to search for past bounties and their amounts?

Tags: support, search, bounties

I was wondering today what the largest bounty ever offered on SO was but I couldn't find a way to figure this out.  Is there a way to search previous bounties? If so is it possible to order by the size of the bounty?

Edit: It appears that the maximum a bounty can be is 500 rep.  I'm still interested in if there is a way to search for past bounty questions along with how much they were worth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62083) on the data explorer.

Apparently, the largest ever was 550 points.

---

Interestingly, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62085/number-of-bounties-opened-and-closed) shows that many more bounties were opened than closed.  I have no idea why.

Comment: I didn't know about the Data Explorer - that's perfect thank you.

Comment: @Gilles -- ah, good to know!

Comment: To explain the 550 figure: in the early days of bounties, users could select any bounty size from 50 to 500 in 50-point increments, just like they can today. However, the system would automatically add 50 more rep for free, regardless of how much the user contributed, so _de facto_ bounty options were 100-550. Auto-awarding of 550-pointers is how we ended up with 275-point bounties, bee tee dubs.

Comment: @Gilles when I click your link I just get a picture of E.F.Codd.

Comment: @Dason Also [All bounties](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/38629), [Top 100 Bounty Earners](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/49794), and a few more. @​Matt: bounties that were opened and not closed would be bounties that expire without anyone being awarded it (i.e. the bounty giver did not select an answer and no answer qualified for an automatic award). *[Manual edit of the links fixed]*